# passing array value as parameter in function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass the array of values fetched from the database as a parameter to a php function.If I echo the value, it doesn't display it.

```
      <?php
  include "config.php";
  $sql="select * from project where comp_id='1'";
  $sql1=mysql_query($sql);
  $rows=array();
  while( $fet=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
  {
   $rows[]=$fet;
   }

  echo fun_parameter($rows);
  function fun_parameter($rows)
   {
     echo" rows". $rows['start_date']."values";   //  not working
   }
    foreach($rows as $row)
     {
     echo $name=$row['start_date'];   /working

     } 

   ?>
```

Comment: post $rows values to see what is coming in the array

Comment: row is a multi-dimensional array use print_r($rows) and see the result. If you want to print then process with loop as it is there in foreach.

Comment: $rows shows the word 'Array'

Comment: @sundar print_r($rows) display the array values like Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [p_id] => 1 [1] => 1 [e_id] => 1.how to extrasct p_id value from this.

Comment: please find the answer

Comment: Passing the value to the function is not the problem. Try to think harder if you want to become a good programmer.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple looping can give the result,

```
 function fun_parameter($rows)
   {
     foreach($rows as $row)
     {
        echo $row['p_id'];   /working
    echo" rows". $row['start_date']."values";
     } 

     //echo" rows". $rows['start_date']."values";   //  not working
   }
```

If you want to fetch particular column from multi dimensional array then take a look into array_column() in php

Answer (score -1):

in your code you are trying to echo an array `$row` without its index specified, you need to loop through that array as it has got mulitple value, use the following code:

```
<?php
  include "config.php";
  $sql="select * from project where comp_id='1'";
  $sql1=mysql_query($sql);
  $rows=array();
  while( $fet=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
  {
   $rows[$i]['start_date']=$fet['start_date'];
   }

  echo fun_parameter($rows);
  function fun_parameter($rows)
   {
   foreach($rows as $row)
     {
    echo" rows". $row['start_date']."values";   //  use loop it will work

     }

   }
    foreach($rows as $row)
     {
     echo $name=$row['start_date'];   // i left this foreach here because you had it in your code    
     }
```

Comment: It display only rowsvalues without any value